# Pattern for request-response flow with inner classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, serialization

I have an application that consists of two processes, one client process with a (SWT-based) GUI and one server process. The client process is very lightweight, which means a lot of GUI operations will have to query the server process or request it to something, for example in response to the user clicking a button or choosing a menu item. This means that there will be a lot of event handlers that looks like this:

```
// Method invoked e.g. in response to the user choosing a menu item
void execute(Event event) {
    // This code is executed on the client, and now we need some info off the server:
    server.execute(new RemoteRequest() {
        public void run() {
            // This code is executed on the server, and we need to update the client 
            // GUI with current progress
            final Result result = doSomeProcessing();
            client.execute(new RemoteRequest() {
                public void run() {
                    // This code is again executed on the client
                    updateUi(result);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

However, since the `server.execute` implies a serialization (it is executed on a remote machine), this pattern is not possible without making the whole class serializable (since the `RemoteRequest` inner classes are not static (just to be clear: it is not a requirement that the `Request` implementation can access the parent instance, for the sake of the application they could be static).

Of course, one solution is to create separate (possibly static inner) classes for the Request and Response, but this hurts readability and makes it harder to understand the execution flow.

I have tried to find any standard pattern for solving this problem, but I have not find anything that answers my concern about readability.

To be clear, there will be a lot of these operations, and the operations are often quite short. Note that `Future` objects are not entirely useful here, since in many cases one request to the server will need to do multiple things on the client (often varying), and it is also not always a result being returned.

Ideally, I would like to be able to write code like this: (obvious pseudo-code now, please disregard the obvious errors in details)

```
String personName = nameField.getText();
async exec on server {
    String personAddress = database.find(personName);
    async exec on client {
        addressField.setText(personAddress);
    }
    Order[] orders = database.searchOrderHistory(personName);
    async exec on client {
        orderListViewer.setInput(orders);
    }
}
```

Now I want to be clear, that the underlying architecture is in place and works well, the reason this solution is there is of course not the above example. The only thing I am looking for is a way to write code like the above, without having to define static classes for each process transition. I hope that I did not just complicate things by giving this example...

Comment: How does this relate to jms? Is this code executed on client or server or another machine?

Comment: Yes, it is. There are cases where the code is executed on the client and on the server. There are also cases where the client executes something on the server which in turn executes something on the client.

Comment: I think we need a bit more details. Are Request/Response your own classes or are they part of some framework? What exactly does execute do?

Comment: I updated the question and tried to be more clear about what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think it would help if you provided a sample use case.

Comment: So you want all your code be on the client, but be executed on server? Some kind of code transfering?

Comment: @Amir They share the same class files, so this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up solving this by creating a base class with a custom serializer that takes care of this. I still hope it is solved in the language eventually.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to use [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) and generic AsynchronousCallbacks. This kind of approach is used in GWT for communicating with the server, for example. Commands are Serializable, AsyncCallback is an interface.

Something along these lines:

```
    // from the client
    server.execute(new GetResultCommand(args), new AsyncCallback<Result>() 
            {
                public void onSuccess(Result result) {
                    updateUi(); // happens on the client
                }
            });
```

The server then needs to receive a command, process it and issue an appropriate response with Result.

Comment: In this case, will `AsyncCallback´ not be a non-static inner class? How is it serialized to the server without requiring the outer class being serialized?

Comment: AsyncCallback won't need to be serialized and sent. The `server` object just keeps a reference to it and then calls it when Result object arrives from the actual server. Only Command and Result need to be Serializable.

Comment: You have a good point, although my problem is that I would have wanted the `GetResultCommand` to be in-line as an anonymous class, and the `AsyncCallback` is not as important for me (though it would be nice).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem the other day.
There is a solution which makes use of anonymous classes (and thus does not require you to define static inner classes), yet makes those anonymous classes be static (and thus not reference the outer object).

Simply define the anonymous classes in a static method, like this:

```
void execute(Event event) {
    static_execute(server, client, event);
}

// An anonymous class is static if it is defined in a static method. Let's use that.
static void static_execute(final TheServer server, final TheClient client, final Event event) {
    server.execute(new RemoteRequest() {
        public void run() {
            final Result result = doSomeProcessing();
            // See note below!
            client.execute(new RemoteRequest() {
                public void run() {
                    updateUi(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The main advantage of this approach, compared to using named static inner classes, is probably that you avoid having to define fields and constructors for those classes.

-- Come to think of it, the same trick probably needs to be applied once more, for the server->client direction. I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I considered a solution like this, but it turns out the code becomes even more complex in my case, written this way.

Answer (score 0):

FIRST:
Without Pattern , if I would suggest, you can make a seperate class for handle all the Patterns. Just pass the instance of each event generated Object to a class and delegate the event request to other classes. Delegation will lead to very clearer approach, just required to use instanceof and then delegate further. Every event can be concise to a seperate place.
Along with the above Approach , yes, COMMAND PATTERN is definately a good option to log requests but you are getting EVENT State for every request raised , so you can try STATE PATTERN as it allows an object to alter its behaviour when state changes.